# Best way to add a button to a RPI4 case

Tags: pi-4, hardware, case

I need to add a single button (mostly for safe shutdown, but I'd also like to hook some scripts to run pre-shutdown) to my RPI 4 builds, however most RPI cases under $20 don't seem to have a place to attach a button.

My requirements are:

- Has to fit securely within a case that also has active cooling. I don't want wires dangling from the GPIO pins, since this will be deployed in the wild and it would easily get ripped out.
- Has to be cheap (<= $1-2 per button, <= $12-15 for case+button), since I'll be deploying this to many devices.
- Has to be customizable through software, though I think this should be easy for anything that uses GPIO.

I'm okay with 3D printing my own case (got a Prusa MK3S+) but I don't have any skills to work with 3D modeling software.

Any ideas?

Comment: not Raspberry Pi specific ... your question would be the same if an Arduino was in the case

Comment: "I'm okay with 3D printing my own case (got a Prusa MK3S+) but I don't have any skills to work with 3D modeling software.

Any ideas?" -> Learn 3D modeling software to make your own case. or look for an existing one on thingyverse for example

Comment: I had already looked on thingiverse and can't find anything relevant. To be clear, I'm not necessarily asking for someone to go and search for a model for me -- I'm asking how people normally attach buttons to cases, and if there's a way to do this cheaply that I'm not aware of. I am just surprised due to the lack of cheap cases or 3D models that have space for a button.